# Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04* on Lenovo L420 Thinkpad, but cannot boot from ISO USB

Tags: boot, lenovo, thinkpad, bios

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04* onto my old Lenovo Thinkpad L420, but for some reason, despite setting the boot order priority to the USB that the ISO is on, the laptop refuses to do anything but boot to Windows 7. I tried following [this PDF guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/LenovoThinkpad_P53_P73_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_Installation_v1.0.pdf) that Lenovo put out, but the BIOS I have (2.6) does not have the options the guide tells me to use. I've hunted around to find out what BIOS edition I need, but to no avail. I feel like I'm stuck; can anyone help?

Edit: It's 18.04.3 to be precise, edited to fix the typo.

Edit 2: Added picture of diagnostic boot screen. [It doesn't show much, to be honest.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edSMI.jpg)

Comment: I would firstly check you have a legitimate Ubuntu, there was no release in 2018-June (18.06) so check you don't have a *forgery*.  Also https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: Ah, mistake on my part. It's Ubuntu 18.04, I got the numbers mixed up. And it's still a valid ISO, I used it to install the OS onto my tower a while back.

Comment: FYI:  I would still check media being valid, unless the other box had the same motherboard, cpu & same chipsets - ie. was identical brand/model/type etc... as it works on another box is only valid if the boxes are identical & same install made.

Comment: That could be a problem. I can't seem to perform the verification check on Win7. The Windows store only lets Win10 users download the Ubuntu terminal. Maybe I ought to flash this USB and just put in a fresh install of the latest LTS version of Ubuntu?

Comment: On a thinkpad sl510 I have to hit I think it's f12 to get asked what device to boot, or just use the blue thinkvantage key to start the system & get asked what device to boot...  The sl510 I used in QA-testing will only boot the installed OS unless the specific keys are pressed before, at or very quickly after boot time  (keys may differ, I would have used device in recent days for 20.04.2 testing, but it was once device of many used and keys differ on different devices)

Comment: Yeah, F12 is how to access the boot device menu on mine, as well. The guide said "Pressing F9function key will allow Legacy and UEFI bootable devices by setting“UEFI/Legacy Boot” to “Both”; otherwise, it will be an unchangeable setting to “UEFI only” " in the startup tab, but doing so only let me reset things to the default state.

Comment: Your L420 is not a P53 as mentioned in the guide so comparing BIOS options does not help you.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm still trying to figure out how to do so, and as I was unable to find a guide for this particular machine (much less the BIOS that it uses), I'm at a loss on what to do.

Comment: With 3 USB ports, try switching to different ports and rebooting. There's another USB/SATA combo port you could try too.

Comment: Try setting all the USB options to on. Refer to this manual for explanations of your BIOS menu and settings: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/434977/Lenovo-Thinkpad-L420.html?page=161#manual

Comment: Alright, I'll give this a shot. Just to note though, this model has two actual USB ports and one that is actually a SATA + USB port that my stick can't interface with. No idea what it's doing there.

Comment: Update: Attempted multiple boots in both USB ports with all USB settings enabled in the BIOS, and with no result.

Comment: The other thing to do is to make sure the boot flag is **still** turned on for this USB device. You can use **fdisk**  on the tower machine to check it.

Comment: Sadly, the tower machine is dead. Died two nights, mostly due to age and exposure to excessive amounts of cat hair. It's a lesson learned - always have a backup laptop or PC on hand in case your main goes kaput. But thank you for all your help.

Comment: You may have to resort to Windows to help you make sure your ISO USB is bootable.  I haven't sworn that it works, but this article could help:  https://www.softwarepro.org/blog/make-partition-bootable-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Under BIOS Boot Options, you might select Diagnostics to see what it is trying to do if you can look at it quickly before it tries to boot anything.

Make sure that your BIOS menu allows you under "I/O Port Access" to enable USB.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/434977/Lenovo-Thinkpad-L420.html?page=165#manual

And Yes, F12 is the hot key to access the boot device menu.

Don't worry, your Lenovo L420 is not entangled with UEFI.  That's one hot mess to avoid with dual boot configurations!

Comment: Made sure everything was set - had the USB (which is being recognized) set to priority 1 and ensured that I/O Port Access permitted the usage of USB, but I'm still getting the same result. I have diagnostics on instead of quick-boot, and while the diagnostics do show, they show way too quickly before vanishing. Is it possible to take a screenshot of them?

Comment: You got a smartphone with a camera? That might be best way. Then upload an image JPEG, PNG, whatever to this question.

Comment: Uploaded. Managed to snag it on my first go somehow. It, admittedly, doesn't show much of anything of import as far as I can tell. It then flashes a single line about diagnostics before going to the Windows boot screen.

Comment: You do have another option.  Go to Windows, download and burn an ISO onto a CD. You could even get 20.04 LTS instead of 18.04... This assumes that you have CD that you can write to.

Comment: I think I will do this instead. My apologies for all the bother so far - you've been of massive help to me and my understanding of Linux in general. Thank you for all you have done.

Comment: No problem.  I have been making Ubuntu happen on Lenovo laptops for over 10 years now.